# Skip Rows When the date is not max Date - DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have sample data as below.

CustomerKey      Date          Amount

C1               20200614      10

c1               20200614      20

c2               20200531      10

c3               20200614      30

c1               20190531      20

c2               20190630      10

c3               20190630      30

I would like to consider the rows where the max date value is 20200614(Max date for the whole table). In the above example, c2 maxdate is 20200531. Hence I need to skip C2. For C1, the maxdate is 20200614 and this equals the maxdate of the table. hence the amount will for c1 will be 20. Similarly, for c3, it is 30. Total Amount for year 2020 is 30+20 = 50.
Similarly, for year 2019, the max date is 20190630. When the user selects year 2019, c1 data should be ignored since its max value is not 20190630.

the desired output is:

For year 2020: c1($30) c3($30)

For Year 2019: c2($10) c3(30)

Please advise how to achieve this using DAX.

Comment: Show us how you want to see the output table?

Comment: Updated the post with sample output data